# With Sql Updates, is there a hint that can be used to not set values if they are the same?

Tags: sql

If I had made the following Sql query against a really large table, this still actually updates the clustered index with new (but same) values:

```
UPDATE dbo.MyTable
SET
ColumnA = ColumnA,
ColumnB = ColumnB
```

I understand why that is, because updating the values (even to the same value) could set off triggers and such so the database needs to honor that.

**Question**

Is there some hint however that could tell the query..."if the value I'm passing is the same as the column, move on"?

**Context**

I have a custom ORM built on top of Dapper.  The ORM is great, but currently passes in all new values in an update statement (it does no diffing).  Ideally I could write something like the following:

```
UPDATE dbo.MyTable
SET
ColumnA = Case When @columnA <> ColumnA Then @columnA Else ColumnA End,
ColumnB = Case When @columnB <> ColumnB Then @columnB Else ColumnB End
```

and get all the performance improvements that come with not actually changing a tables underlying data.  But the problem is that setting a column to itself is as costly as setting it to a new value.

Also, a 'where' clause doesn't really work when some of the columns might be changed and others might not be.

Comment: Use mysql: it has this behaviour built in

Comment: Would mysql increment a rowversion field even if all the values were the same?

Comment: I'm not sure you can avoid the WHERE clause. It should work if it takes the form "WHERE A <> @A OR B <> @B...". The other alternative is to add another UPDATE trigger. I can't see either performing terribly well, though. I'm not familiar with the MERGE command, but there's some mention that this could be useful.

Comment: The MERGE command is a good thing for me to look at.  I've always avoided it because it seems unnecessarily complicated, but if it handles this situation maybe it will work.

Comment: AFAIK mysql doesn't have row version numbers. It does have a datatype `timestamp` that auto updates when you tough another column, but that too won't update unless a column value *changes*, despite executing an update

Comment: Got it...timestamp == rowversion.  That's interesting that MySql keeps the timestamp if you try to update a row with the same values.  This is not the case with MSSQL.